# Prevent javascript from running when screen width is less or more than

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 menus that are contained on the same page but in different locations. One appears when I have screen width > 555px and the parent div is set as display:none when under this size. The other is display:none when 555px or over and shows when less than 555px. Its the same menu but one is on a different section of the page for mobile/smaller screens.

I have javascript on some of the drop down options on the menu and it works for the first menu but not the second, I believe because the js is still attempting to run for the display:none so on the second attempt (on the small screens) it doesn't work.

I'm probably over-complicating what needs to be done but I've attempted to create some code that uses js to create the div that contains the menu code for desktop and mobile and removes them when it shouldn't... so a media query version controlled by js rather than css that rather than hide the div and content will actually make it not be present.

I'm a complete novice at javascript and have just attempted to adapt other code I've seen, basically all I want to do is when >555px browser width add  and when it moves under remove  then I can use the same code down the page to add/remove div id="y"...

```
function DynamicDiv() {
        var dynDiv = document.createElement("div");
        dynDiv.id = "search-holder1";
        dynDiv.innerHTML = "Created using JavaScript";
        document.body.appendChild(dynDiv);
    }

var elem = document.getElementById("search-holder1");

function myFunction(x) {
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches

     DynamicDiv();

    } else {

        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 555px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way:

```
function chooseMenu() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width > 555) {
        //Add your div
    else {
        //If div is in document then remove, and add mobile div
    }
}
window.onresize = chooseMenu;
```

You should probably do the same function at the beggining with an anonymous function too.

Comment: Thanks, certainly looks neater. It's the adding and removing the html (the div) that I'm struggling with though. Want it to simply add <div id="search" ></div> or if else then remove the above from where the script is on the page. If that's not possible then add to the top of a parent div with I'd "content".